# Why is SKScene's view property not being set when presenting a scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-development

I've recently updated to the latest "stable" release of Xcode, Swift, and SDKs. After the update, `GameScene.view?` always returns `nil`. It seems SKScene's view property is not being set upon presenting a given scene. This leaves me unable to add any gesture recognizers to my game (using the presenting view at least).

Any idea as to whether I'm overlooking something or is this maybe a bug? I've added gesture recognizers to SpriteKit games in the past using essentially the same implementation shown in the code below.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334))
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        
        // Present the scene
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    let ballAnchor: BallAnchor
    let ball: Ball
    
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer
    let doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer
    
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        self.ballAnchor = BallAnchor()
        self.ball = Ball()

        self.tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        self.doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

        super.init(size: size)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        physicsWorld.gravity = .zero
        
        backgroundColor = Color.background
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        
        ball.configure()
        ball.delegate = ballAnchor
        
        ballAnchor.configure()
        ballAnchor.anchor(ball)
        self.addChild(ballAnchor.sprite)
        
        tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.tap(sender:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 override func sceneDidLoad() {}
```

With template code

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {}
```

Comment: Ah...works perfect, thank you. Do you know why sceneDidLoad() is now the default scene setup location over didMove(to view: SKView)?

Comment: I'm also on 12.1. If you check the "integrate Gameplaykit" checkbox when creating your project you get the sceneDidLoad() func and if you uncheck it you get didMove func.  But the GameViewController template is set up accordingly. Did you change the GameViewController code?